# Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

When I am trying to get active(log in) person as authenticated in my controller class to load apporative fragment(uprojects.htm) in home.html by using thymeleaf "th:replace", I am getting isAuthenticated control as a null. I could not solve the problem. Need help.

My controller class is as here. in home mapping there is check for user for isAuthencated:

```java
    private UserService userService;
    
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String displayHomePage (Model model){
            if(auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && auth.isAuthenticated()){
                model.addAttribute("template", "uprojects");
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("template", "login");
            }
            return "home";
        }
        @RequestMapping("/nfeatures")
        public String displayNFeaturesPage (Model model){
            model.addAttribute("template","nfeatures");
            return "home";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping("/pricing")
        public String displayPricingPage (Model model){
            model.addAttribute("template","pricing");
            return "home";
        }
        @GetMapping("/registration")
        public String registrationForm(Model model) {
            UserDto user = new UserDto();
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("template","registration");
            return "home";
        }
        @PostMapping("/registration")
        public String registration(
                @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserDto userDto,
                BindingResult result,
                Model model) {
            User existingUser = userService.findUserByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    
            if (existingUser != null)
                result.rejectValue("email", null,
                        "User already registered !!!");
    
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("user", userDto);
                return "/registration";
            }
    
            userService.saveUser(userDto);
            return "redirect:/registration?success";
        }
```

My security class options that for spring security 6:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/fragments/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/nfeatures/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/pricing/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**", "/uprojects/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
                    .formLogin((form) -> form
                            .loginPage("/home")
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                            .permitAll()
                    )
                    .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

home.html page which is severe main entry point to my web application,

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>
        <div th:replace="${template} :: ${template}"></div>
    </div>
    <footer th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the authentication from inside your controller method like this:

```
        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public String displayHomePage (Model model){
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if(auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && auth.isAuthenticated()){
                model.addAttribute("template", "uprojects");
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("template", "login");
            }
            return "home";
        }
```